# How to alter a javascript extension and use it in my project without waiting for approvals?

Tags: javascript, github, ember.js

I'm using an extension in my project called cytoscape in my Ember.js project and along with it, [cytoscape-context-menushttps](https://github.com/iVis-at-Bilkent/cytoscape.js-context-menus).  I needed to make one tiny change to it to accommodate the needs of my project.  I have done so and it works great (I tested it locally by simply monkey-patching the code in the relevant JS file in the extension and confirming it works).

I just want to know, how am I supposed to incorporate this change into my project, without having to manually change that bit of code every time we build our project?  I know that I can pull down the repo and make a PR on it and get it approved, but that could take days/weeks/months.  There must be a way I can manage this myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fork the repository and use your own fork as the dependency.  Maintain your fork and keep it up to date with the upstream repository.  Switch back whenever your pull request is incorporated.